What libraries did I missed in this u-boot compile?
In file included from ./arch/arm/include/asm/armv7.h:60,
                 from arch/arm/mach-stm32mp/stm32mp1/psci.c:8:
arch/arm/mach-stm32mp/stm32mp1/psci.c: In function 'psci_arch_cpu_entry':
arch/arm/mach-stm32mp/stm32mp1/psci.c:232:21: error: 'TAMP_BACKUP_MAGIC_NUMBER' undeclared (first use in this function)
  232 |  writel(0xFFFFFFFF, TAMP_BACKUP_MAGIC_NUMBER);
......
arch/arm/mach-stm32mp/stm32mp1/psci.c: In function 'psci_cpu_off':
arch/arm/mach-stm32mp/stm32mp1/psci.c:159:29: error: 'STM32_RCC_BASE' undeclared (first use in this function)
  159 | #define RCC_MP_GRSTCSETR   (STM32_RCC_BASE + 0x0404)
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./arch/arm/include/asm/io.h:31:55: note: in definition of macro '__arch_putl'
   31 | #define __arch_putl(v,a)  (*(volatile unsigned int *)(a) = (v))
      |                                                       ^
arch/arm/mach-stm32mp/stm32mp1/psci.c:344:3: note: in expansion of macro 'writel'
  344 |   writel(RCC_MP_GRSTCSETR_MPUP1RST, RCC_MP_GRSTCSETR);
      |   ^~~~~~
arch/arm/mach-stm32mp/stm32mp1/psci.c:344:37: note: in expansion of macro 'RCC_MP_GRSTCSETR'
  344 |   writel(RCC_MP_GRSTCSETR_MPUP1RST, RCC_MP_GRSTCSETR);
...

Did I have some config problem or missing libraries?
My compile command: cd u-boot && make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi- -j$(THREADS)
I met a problem about start.S and I customed stack address in .config fixed it.
I think if I can disable PSCI, I can fix this. But I cannot.

The errors doesn't com from the linker. So, no library is missing but a header file.
